# How do I remove an element from a list by value?

Tags: scala, list, dictionary, filter, scala-collections

I am currently working on a function that takes in a Map[String, List[String]] and a String as arguments. The map contains a user Id and the IDs of films that they liked. What I need to do is, to return a List[List[String]] which contains the other movies that where liked by the user who liked the movie that was passed into the function.

The function declaration looks as follows:

```
def movies(m: Map[String, List[String]], mov: String) : List[List[String]]= {

}
```

So lets imagine the following:

```
val m1 : [Map[Int, List[String]]] = Map(1 ‐> List("b", "a"), 2 ‐> List("y", "x"), 3 ‐> List("c", "a"))
val movieID = "a"
movies(m1, movieId)
```

This should return:

```
List(List("b"), List("c"))
```

I have tried using

```
m1.filter(x => x._2.contains(movieID))
```

So that only Lists containing movieID are kept in the map, but my problem is that I need to remove movieID from every list it occurs in, and then return the result as a List[List[String]].

Answer (score 2):

You could  use `collect`:

```
val m = Map("1" -> List("b", "a"), "2" -> List("y", "x"), "3" -> List("c", "a"))

def movies(m: Map[String, List[String]], mov: String) = m.collect {
  case (_, l) if l.contains(mov) => l.filterNot(_ == mov)
}

movies(m, "a") //List(List(b), List(c))
```

Problem with this approach is, that it would iterate over every movie list twice, the first time with `contains` and the second time with `filterNot`. We could optimize it tail-recursive function, which would look for element and if found just return list without it:

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def movies(m: Map[String, List[String]], mov: String) = {

   @tailrec
   def withoutElement[T](l: List[T], mov: T, acc: List[T] = Nil): Option[List[T]] = {
      l match {
        case x :: xs if x == mov => Some(acc.reverse ++ xs)
        case x :: xs => withoutElement(xs, mov, x :: acc)
        case Nil => None
      }
   }

   m.values.flatMap(withoutElement(_, mov))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution from Krzysztof is a good one. Here's an alternate way to traverse every `List` just once.

```
def movies(m: Map[String, List[String]], mov: String) =
  m.values.toList.flatMap{ss =>
    val tpl = ss.foldLeft((false, List.empty[String])){
      case ((_,res), `mov`)  => (true, res)
      case ((keep,res), str) => (keep, str::res)
    }
    if (tpl._1) Some(tpl._2) else None
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
  object DemoAbc extends App {
  val m1 = Map(1 -> List("b", "a"), 2 -> List("y", "x"), 3 -> List("c", "a"))
  val movieID = "a"

  def movies(m: Map[Int, List[String]], mov: String): List[List[String]] = {
    val ans = m.foldLeft(List.empty[List[String]])((a: List[List[String]], b: (Int, List[String])) => {
      if (b._2.contains(mov))
        b._2.filter(_ != mov) :: a
      else a
    })

    ans
  }

  print(movies(m1, movieID))
}
```

Comment: ooh yeah actually I thought he forgot to add List(x,y) in the ans so I didn't excluded @jwvh

Comment: I am not entirely sure how any of these algorithms work, but they are not producing the desired result. In the test that I am actually trying to run, there are over 600 user IDs and over 150,000 movie IDs. And when 'movies(m, "912")' is called, then the length of the result should be 80 but I am getting a length of 1 with these.

Comment: @k1888914 any of the other answers working fine for you if now then may be you got the functionality wrong.

Comment: I mean, the example I specified above was just an example of what I am trying to achieve but on a much larger scale. The actual test data is far greater in size.

Comment: One or two of them did work for the example specified but when running them using the actual data, it produces the wrong result.

Comment: if it's running for the example it should run for all other or you might don't know the functionality please check it onces

Comment: Im not sure what you mean exactly.